# How to get ride of all typeScript build erros while compiling the build

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeerror, react-typescript

I am working on project,i have to deploy the build to the server. But whenever, i run the build. Type Script build errors starts showing. I already have put "src" folder to exclude in tsconfig.json. As shown below

[image]

As you can see, I have put the src folder in exclude, so it should exclude this whole folder while doing type check. But still it is showing type Script errors. As,

[image]

Anyone who can help. I don't want to write // @ts-nocheck . As there are tons of files in the whole project. Anyone who can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: [Why does a module in the exclude list still get picked up by the compiler?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Module%20Resolution.md#why-does-a-module-in-the-exclude-list-still-get-picked-up-by-the-compiler)

Comment: Also, are you doing an `npm install` before the TypeScript build?